# Calculate the year-year Growth

Tags: microsoft-excel

Assuming i have a short income statement for the next 12 months.

[image]

Now I want to create another table, for the first three years, something like this

```
x                Year 1 | Year 2 | Year 3 
==============================================
Expenses Cum            |        | 
----------------------------------------------
Revenue  Cum            |        |
```

How can i do this in a clever way, maybe deduce from the month over month growth and apply this to the years, i want to create it using some form of formula and not rely on static value.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a pivot table might be useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(did you notice you have two times the seventh month in your model and that there is an error in the cumulative revenues calculation? For example cum. revenue in M5 is 12k and not 10k)?*

**Exponential growth**
In a lot of cases, *growth* is considered to be exponential. Exponential growth can be calculated as: `new / old - 1`. So from M8 to M9 your direct expenses growth is 5953 / 5778 - 1 = 0,03 = 3%. If you have your average growth calculated over each month, you can calculate the aggregated growth by calculating: ( 1 + growth ) ^ 12 - 1. So a monthly growth of 3% results in an annual growth of ( 1 + 0,03 ) ^ 12 - 1 = 1,43 - 1 = 0,43 = 43% (rounded to two digits).

**In your case...**
In your case, you start growing from zero, so that will result in some exaggerated exponential growth figures (for example from M3 to M4 you double your revenues, which is likely in the startup phase, but unlikely further on. There are several tricks you can apply to overcome this, like calculate the a running [moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average) and use that as basis for your future estimations.

*But* if I look closer to your data, it appears that your growth is merely linear (constant increase over time) and not exponential. I made a chart and put some trendlines in it. It looks like this:

[image: Expenses and revenues over time]

Excel can add the regression formula in a graph. In your case, your revenues increases around 2670 per month and your expenses around 72,4 per month.

If you want to use those number to calculate the cumulative values over a year, you can use: `12 * monthly_value_at_the_beginning + 66 * monthly_increase`. The 66 is because the *monthly* increase is added 1 time for month 2, 2 times for month 3, ..., 11 times for month 12. And 1+2+...+10+11 = 1/2 * 11 * 12 = 66. In your case this results in: `revenue  = previous year's revenue + 32000` and `expense = previous your's expense + 47500` (all rounded to nearest half thousands).

Based on these numbers and correcting your faulty cumulative revenue calculation, I come tho something like this (rounded to the nearest thousand):

[image: Future cumulative revenues and expenses]

Note: you can use the `LINEST` and `GROWTH` functions to calculate those numbers exactly.

Comment: FORECAST as well can be handy for linear prediction